# Finding distance from point within cell to border of that cell - when moving along vector

Tags: generics, math, trigonometry

I'm trying to calculate how long route my object will travel within given cell, before it moves to another cell.

That is what really matters to me, but also I need to know what is the point of crossing (but it would be trivial if I knew distance from starting point).

Some of my game rules are :

- Every cell might have different movement cost
- Movement cost is exactly the same across whole cell
- I move object from point A to point B in straight line
- I know starting object location and it's direction (as vector)
- cells have borders on lines which are full integers on net of numbers.

What I need in the end :

- where exactly unit will run out of movement points if it keeps going in said direction.

So for each cell I need to calculate :

- distance from a point within cell to this cells border - when moving along direction vector.

I think I skipped some trigonometry lesson, or I'm too sleepy, but I could not have found either any simple solution to this problem, neither quick and dirty workaround.

[image]

Comment: The distance formula is C squared = A squared + B squared.  In other words, find the change in X, square it, find the change in Y, square it, add the squares together, and take the square root.

Answer (score 0):

I made some function, that does what I needed. I'm not sure if it will be completely robust (I'm especially afraid of some float rounding that will result in putting point that is *on* border - on wrong side of that border and result in 0 distance).
It's also printing a lot and assigning a lot, but I plan on shortening it, improving it and updating this answer in future. I wanted to share what have worked quite well - in case someone has similar problem / or in case I won't update it anytime soon.

```
Vector2D cellCross(Vector2D startPoint, Vector2D direction)
{
    printf("start point [x:%f|y:%f]\n",startPoint.x,startPoint.y);
    printf("direction [x:%f|y:%f]\n",direction.x,direction.y);
    if (!direction.isNormalized())
    {
        printf("in cellCross() : direction vector must be normalized!\n");
        throw "bad arg";
    }

    //cell center is like Vector2D(x,y) from my image
    Vector2D cellCenter (floor(startPoint.x)+0.5 , floor(startPoint.y)+0.5);
    printf("cell center [x:%f|y:%f]\n",cellCenter.x,cellCenter.y);
    //relative point is like Vector2D(m,n) from my image
    Vector2D relativePoint ( startPoint.x-cellCenter.x , startPoint.y-cellCenter.y );
    printf("relative point [x:%f|y:%f]\n",relativePoint.x,relativePoint.y);
    Vector2D targetCorner;
    if (direction.x>0)
        targetCorner.x=0.5;
    else
        targetCorner.x=-0.5;
    if (direction.y>0)
        targetCorner.y=0.5;
    else
        targetCorner.y=-0.5;
    printf("target corner [x:%f|y:%f]\n",targetCorner.x,targetCorner.y);

    double x_diff = targetCorner.x - relativePoint.x;
    double y_diff = targetCorner.y - relativePoint.y;
    printf("x_diff : %f\n",x_diff);
    printf("y_diff : %f\n",y_diff);

    Vector2D crossPoint;

    if (fabs(x_diff*direction.x) > fabs(y_diff*direction.y))
    { // we will cross at (targetCorner.x,[unknown]y)
        crossPoint.x = targetCorner.x;
        crossPoint.y = relativePoint.y + (direction.y * (x_diff/direction.x) );
    }
    else
    { // we will cross at ([unknown]x,targetCorner.y)
        crossPoint.y = targetCorner.y;
        crossPoint.x = relativePoint.x + (direction.x * (y_diff/direction.y) );
    }
    crossPoint.x+=cellCenter.x;
    crossPoint.y+=cellCenter.y;
    printf("cross point [x:%f|y:%f]\n",crossPoint.x,crossPoint.y);
    printf("distance : %f\n",startPoint.distanceTo(crossPoint) );
    return crossPoint;
}
```

To present one egzample - for :

```
Vector2D startPoint (2.0,0.5);
Vector2D direction = Vector2D(10,-30).normalized();
Vector2D endingPoint = cellCross(startPoint,direction);
```

it printed :

```
start point [x:2.000000|y:0.500000]
direction [x:0.316228|y:-0.948683]
cell center [x:2.500000|y:0.500000]
relative point [x:-0.500000|y:0.000000]
target corner [x:0.500000|y:-0.500000]
x_diff : 1.000000
y_diff : -0.500000
cross point [x:2.166667|y:0.000000]
distance : 0.527046
```

which looks like roughly correct outcome for me and my calculator.

Than I could've just multiply distance from function result by movement cost for that tile and repeat calculation for next tile, until my unit goes to negative amount of movement points. Quick correction by moving it by last_tile_movement_cost * movement_points in same direction should place it right where it should have landed.